# How do I get the height of the recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, height, android-recyclerview

In my app I have a GridlayoutManager combined with a recyclerview. What I would like to do is **get the height of the recyclerview**, since I want to have an even 3x4 grid of imageviews.

The code below gets the height and width of the device.

```
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) someView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int height = (size.y)/4;
    int width = (size.x)/3;
```

This code sets the parameters (height and width) of the imageview.

```
Imageview imgView = ...findbyid...;

Imageview imgView.getLayoutParams().height = (size.y)/4;
          imgView.getLayoutParams().width = (size.x)/3;
```

This works fine for my width, but not for my height. The reason being I can't use the whole screen size, as I have to account for the `Toolbar` and a `sliding tab` below it. [See image of layout here!!](http://i.imgur.com/yshvfKu.png)

As you can see from the image I only want the height of the recyclerview.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks :)